# How to increase the perfomance of Thrift client Scanner queries to Hbase

Tags: hbase, thrift

I have used thrift interface with c# to get realtime data from Hbase. My problem is that, filter queries taking too much time for the response from hbase. Sample code is given below:

```
string TableName="testtable";

Dictionary<byte[], byte[]> attributes = new Dictionary<byte[], byte[]>(); 
TScan scanFilter = new TScan();

scanFilter.FilterString = ToByteArray("((RowFilter(<=,'binary:1053_1371222000')) AND (RowFilter(>=,'binary:1053_1371217740'))) OR (RowFilter(<=,'binary:1055_1371222000')) AND (RowFilter(>=,'binary:1055_1371217740')))");

var scanner = _client.scannerOpenWithScan(ToByteArray(TableName), scanFilter, attributes);

for (var entry = _client.scannerGet(scanner); entry.Count > 0; entry = _client.scannerGet(scanner))
{

            foreach (var rowResult in entry)
            {
        string rowkey = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rowResult.Row);
                Console.Write("{0} => ", rowkey);

    }
```

}

```
_client.scannerClose(scanner);
```

My question is that:

1) how many ways we can improve the performance(optimization) of Thrift query to hbase.
2) how to cache the Thrift query response on Hbase.
3) how to manage load balancing of Thrift server on Master node.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Cache here. That may reduce the time for iteration to some extend.

```
var entry = _client.scannerGetList(scanner,100);
```

Here scanner is the ScannerId returned and the numeric represents the number of rows to be cached.

Am a newbie in this field. You can try it , but am not sure about the performance gain which can be achieved.